# jdbc program written in servlet using oracle in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jdbc

I have searched for the answers, but I'm getting relevant answers. Even though my exception is not new, but I'm unable to find the answer. I am getting an exception, The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this

```
 request.Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.src.pkg.DepositServlet.doPost(DepositServlet.java:82)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.37 logs.

I will send my code also. It is pointing in the doPost() method of DepositServlet that too it is showing error to the below line-
Statement st = ((java.sql.Connection) con).createStatement();
Please help me in solving this problem.

```
//DepositServlet.java
package com.src.pkg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.sun.corba.se.pept.transport.Connection;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DepositServlet
 */
public class DepositServlet extends HttpServlet {
    Connection con;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */


    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","rekha");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int ano = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("accno"));
    float amt = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("amount"));
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    try
    {
    Statement st = ((java.sql.Connection) con).createStatement();
        int n = st.executeUpdate("update account set balance = balance + "+amt+" where accno = "+ano);
        if(n==1)
        {
            out.println("<body bgcolor=green>");
            out.println("<h1> Successfully deposited </h1>");
        }
        if(n==0)
        {
            out.println("<body bgcolor=wheat>");
            out.println("<h1> Wrong a/c no </h1>");
        }
        st.close();
    }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            out.println("<body bgcolor=red>");
                out.println("<h1> Server problem </h1>");
            }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
        }
    }


//web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>deposit.html</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>

    <servlet-name>DepositServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.src.pkg.DepositServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DepositServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DepositServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>


//deposit.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="cyan">
<center>
<h1> Deposit screen</h1>
<form action = "./DepositServlet" method = "post">
A/C No <input type="text" name="accno"> <br> <br>
Amount <input type="text" name="amount"> <br> <br>
<input type="submit" value="deposit">
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: com.sun.corba.se.pept.transport.Connection is not the Connection you're looking for - you want java.sql.Connection

Answer (score 1):

The **Problem** part:

**First,** you need to know that this is a **dangerous and unstable** thing to do.

The "**init**" method is called **once**, when the **servlet is loaded**. The "doPost" method might potentially be called many **hundreds or thousands** of times over a period of weeks, months or years.

**Almost all** databases will "time out" and **disconnect** open connections if they are left open for too long. 
If you only open a connection in "init" it may even "time out" **before** you get to use it. This also implies that you have **no way of re-openin**g a closed connection **without reloading the servlet**, ie.**restarting** your web server.

All in all, opening a database connection is "init" is a **bad thing** to do.

===================

Now, the **Solution** part.

<s>You should actually be doing this in a listener, more specifically a ServletContextListener.</s>

**Thanks @stdunbar** for your comment.

1. (basic solution) You can create connection **inside doPost()** instead of init().

OR

2. (advanced solution ) You can use **connection pooling** like Tomcat JDBC or DBCP2.

Comment: And how is your solution any different?  You've made it worse by keeping the connection open the entire lifetime of the server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggetions. I will try with your given solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at the database [connection pooling docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) from Tomcat.  Ultimately you need three things.  The first would be a META-INF/context.xml file at the root of your web application.  This would look something like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Context path="">
  <Resource name="jdbc/someName"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="system"
            password="rekha"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
</Context>
```

Then, in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application you'll need to put the Oracle thin driver jar/zip file.  Lastly, when you need a database connection your code will look something like:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

private static final String dbJNDIName = "jdbc/someName"; // matches context.xml name

public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();

        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup( "java:comp/env/" + dbJNDIName );
        if( ds != null ) {
            return ds.getConnection();
         }
         else {
             // log error somehow
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            // log error
        }
    return( null );
}
```

Lastly, when you need a database connection in your code you'll do so by calling this method.  You've got a java.sql.Connection cast in your code which, with the correct import, won't be needed.  Be sure to still close the connection you get back - the pool will do the right thing.